# attribute error: 'dict' object has no attribute find_all error

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I was recently working on parsing html txt using beautiful soup using python. I wrote the following code for scraping the tables so I could print them.

```
#TABLES 

# let's grab the all pages code.
pages_dict = filing_documents[document_id]['pages_code']  
        
# initalize a dictionary to store all the anchors we find.
tables_dict = {}
new_tables_dict = {}

# loop through each page
for page_num in pages_dict:
    
    # grab the actual text
    page_code = pages_dict[page_num]
    
    # find all the anchors in the page, that have the attribute 'name'
    tables_found = page_code.find_all('table')
    
    # number of anchors found
    num_found = len(tables_found)
    
    # each page is going to be checked, so let's have another dictionary that'll house all the anchors found.
    tables_dict[page_num]= {(table_id + 1): table for table_id, table in enumerate(tables_found)} 

    

    if len(tables_dict) != 0:

        # loop through the dictionary
        for table_id in tables_dict:

            # grab the table
            table_html = tables_dict[table_id]
            
            # grab all the rows.
            table_rows = table_html.find_all('tr')
            
            # parse the table, first loop through the rows, then each element, and then parse each element.
            parsed_table = [
                [element.get_text(strip=True) for element in row.find_all('td')]
                for row in table_rows
            ]
            
            # keep the original just to be safe.
            tables_dict[table_id]['original_table'] = table_html
            
            # add the new parsed table.
            tables_dict[table_id]['parsed_table'] = parsed_table
            
            # here some additional steps you can take to clean up the data - Removing '$'.
            parsed_table_cleaned = [
                [element for element in row if element != '$']
                for row in parsed_table
            ]
            
            # here some additional steps you can take to clean up the data - Removing Blanks.
            parsed_table_cleaned = [
                [element for element in row if element != None]
                for row in parsed_table_cleaned
            ]

        
    else:
        
        # if there are no tables then just have the id equal NONE
        tables_dict[1]['original_table'] = None
        tables_dict[1]['parsed_table'] = None



filing_documents[document_id]['anchor_search'] = link_anchor_dict
filing_documents[document_id]['tables_search'] = tables_dict    



a = filing_documents[document_id]['tables_search']['table_id']['parsed_table']
print(a)
```

When I try to print a, it comes up with the following error. Is there anything I can add or reduce to fix this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Vanya\Desktop\FINAL\our_code (1).py", line 434, in 
table_rows = table_html.find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: It is exactly what it says. Python's dict datatype has no "find_all()" method. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: It appears that when you do `pages_dict[page_num]`, you are expecting to retrieve a BeautifulSoup object from the `pages_dict` dictionary. But you don't; you instead retrieve another dictionary. We cannot explain any further without your actual data.